# Predicting occurrence of frequent values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have been given a set of sales figures and have been asked to predict how many of the similar sales can be made based on the current values or the frequent sales figures I have.

I am planning to use excel and tableau but wanted to leverage the power of python to do the task.

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h2>SALES DATA</h2>
<table width="211">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>SALE 1</td>
<td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 2</td>
<td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 3</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 4</td>
<td>18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 5</td>
<td>23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 6</td>
<td>19</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 7</td>
<td>25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 8</td>
<td>17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 9</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 10</td>
<td>26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 11</td>
<td>16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 12</td>
<td>34</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 13</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 14</td>
<td>31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 15</td>
<td>25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 16</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 17</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 18</td>
<td>24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 19</td>
<td>15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 20</td>
<td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 21</td>
<td>36</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 22</td>
<td>32</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 23</td>
<td>35</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 24</td>
<td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 25</td>
<td>19</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 26</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 27</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 28</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 29</td>
<td>24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 30</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 31</td>
<td>16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 32</td>
<td>13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 33</td>
<td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 34</td>
<td>35</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 35</td>
<td>34</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 36</td>
<td>15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 37</td>
<td>24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 38</td>
<td>19</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 39</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 40</td>
<td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 41</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 42</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 43</td>
<td>32</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 44</td>
<td>13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 45</td>
<td>33</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 46</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 47</td>
<td>25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 48</td>
<td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 49</td>
<td>16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 50</td>
<td>32</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 51</td>
<td>33</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 52</td>
<td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 53</td>
<td>31</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 54</td>
<td>18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 55</td>
<td>17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 56</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 57</td>
<td>25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 58</td>
<td>22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 59</td>
<td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 60</td>
<td>18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 61</td>
<td>23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SALE 62</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Please run the snippet to see the table.

Comment: So your input is this HTML, and the output must be a single valued result?

Comment: Is the goal to predict new sales from previous sales?

Comment: The reason I had to include the HTML was to display the table clearly. If I paste the table in the question the format is messed.

Comment: Yes I want to use the sales figures in the SALES DATA to predict the future sales.

Comment: for example for sale 2, sale 20 and sale 24 we made 14 sales. So I am hoping to predict if I will have 14 sales in the furture for any sales . I have to predict atleast 7 such sales that might occur in the future from the data in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from collections import defaultdict

mydoc=ElementTree(file='Stack.html')
value=0
sales=[]
values=[]

for e in mydoc.findall('.//tr'):
    sales.append(e.find('.//td[1]').text)
    values.append(e.find('.//td[2]').text)
mylist=list(zip(values,sales))
mydict=defaultdict(list)
for values,sales in mylist:
    mydict[values].append(sales)
print (mydict.items())
```

you may use  itervalue (preferable), for getting the value for website you may use [BeutifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/)